# Symbol multiply defined

Tags: c

I have some mistake with .c file and .h file here. Could you please help me to find the reason.

**file1.h**

```
#ifndef FILE_H_1
#define FILE_H_1
u32 function_1(u32 data);
u32 function_2(u16 data);
#endif
```

**file2.h**

```
#ifndef FILE_H_2
#define FILE_H_2
u32 function_1(u32 data);
u32 function_3(u16 data, u16 reg);
#endif
```

**main.c**

```
#include "file1.h"
static u32 function_3 (u32 data)
{
     //do something;
}

void main() {
     u32 m = function_1(0);
}
```

**file1.c**

```
#include "file1.h"
u32 function_1 (u32 data) {
      return 2*data;
}
u32 function_2(u16 data) {
      return 3*data;
}
```

**file2.c**

```
#include "file2.h"
u32 function_1(u32 data){
     return data;
}
u32 function_3(u16 data,u16 reg){
     return 5*data + reg;
}
```

It compile OK, but it has error linker.
The issue is "u32 function_3(u16 data) incompatible with u32 function_3(u16 data, u16 reg). Although I only #include "file1.h" in main.c.

Please help me to fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: where is the `main()`?

Comment: Don't use the same name for different functions.

Comment: There should be semicolons at the ends of returns in both function. Also, at what line does the error appears ?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to separate the code chunks (of different files) and give the compilation command

Comment: Thanks for your edition.

Comment: The question needs straightening out. It is unclear whether it is a compile time error (as the error message suggests) or a linker error (as the current state of the code suggests).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

C++ permits functions with the same name (with different parameters), but C does not.  You can eliminate your error by just modifying one of those function names.

Comment: Oddly enough, even before editing the question, this error doesn't occur because of his use of 'static'. It worked as intended.

Comment: Careful reading of the OP question (all edited versions) turns up an incomplete picture.  Specifically, the error mentions the function with 2 16 bit parameters, and that declaration is in file2.h, not included from main.c, as he said.  So why did the compiler know of it?  Perhaps it's a linker error report.  But the OP shows no linker details.  The question could be nit-picked to death, but the most important thing is that he get his declarations and definitions and uses consistent.

Comment: That's right. It is a linker error report. And I don't know how to show the OP this is two function differently. Because, in each file.c , I have functions with same name. I used "Static" in main.c. But it does not make the code better.

Comment: The main purpose is  the files .c contain the functions with the same name. But each function has the different work.  And if I want to use file_1.c. I just #include "file_1.h".

Answer (score -1):

After heavily fixing your supplied example (look at the edits) I run into the following error:

`function_1` is defined twice.

I cannot reproduce the error you experience.

Maybe I edited your example in an unintended way. Please change it so that the error you are experiencing occurs.

Comment: what is the downvote for? If you clarify further I'll edit the answer